# how to check (test) 3-D Secure option in sagepay test api using php?

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to implement sagepay payment method using cUrl in PHP and all set But I haven't Idea for check 3 secure functionality. they didn't provide a card detail which help to redirect to 3-d secure page(check 3d secure) .

If some one have idea please provide me I spend lot of time......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I am not very familiar with sagepay payment method But may this documentation helpful for you.

https://test.sagepay.com/documentation/#3-d-secure

The steps are :

1) VEReq – Verification Request – This is when we contact 3d Secure to see if the shopper is registered for 3d Secure.

2) VERes – Verification Response – Is when 3d Secure confirm back to us that the card is registered and they give us the password page URL to forward on to you.

3) PAReq – Password Request – You will then re-direct your shopper through to the password pages so they can enter their 3d Secure password and complete verification.

4) PARes – Password Response – 3d Secure will then confirm back to you if the shopper has either passed or failed the verification.